# Converting OCaml to F#: OCaml equivalent of F# spec, specifically initialization

Tags: f#, documentation, ocaml, specifications

In the process of converting the OCaml [Format module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html) to F# I find that I need to understand the initialization process in detail. For F# this is explained in section [12.5 Program Execution](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997230) of the F# spec. While the [OCaml documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/index.en.html) page list several good documents, I am unable to find any document that gives the same level of detail as found in the F# spec.

Are there any documents that give the corresponding level of detail for OCaml initialization?

Comment: Ultimately an OCaml program is a series of module implementations.  Evaluation of modules is described (extremely briefly) in [Section 6.11.2 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual019.html#6.11.2).  In essence, each top level form is evaluated in turn.  I suspect you need more detail than this, but I don't know where to look.  Maybe you have a more specific question?

Comment: @JeffreyScofield There is a more specific question some where down the line, but at present I can't even formulate it. When I post those kinds half understood questions here they only put a burden on those answering. I find it better for me to do as much research as possible before asking.

Comment: I think your best bet is http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/language.html - evaluation order is mostly top-down left-to-right, but there are notable exceptions in the core language, where it is unspecified (for example, tuple or record components). The module language has fewer surprises.

Comment: When I orginally did research before asking this question I could not find what I needed in a document. The only way I know of to get the detail needed about initialization is to read the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, is there a specification manual for OCaml like the one for F#? No

I spent an hour today looking and still could not find one. I goggled, check some OCaml mailing list and looked over all of the documents from the OCaml site. Others in an OCaml mailing list also noted the lack of an OCaml specification manual.

As always with these no answers, if someone does answer here with a reference to the OCaml spec manual like the one for F# then I will gladly give them the accept vote.

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer any information about OCaml module initialization, but I did port the Format module to F# as part of my [`FSharp.Compatibility`](https://github.com/jack-pappas/FSharp.Compatibility) project. If you want to have a look, it's available here:

https://github.com/jack-pappas/FSharp.Compatibility/tree/master/FSharp.Compatibility.OCaml.Format